# Smart contract calls another smart contract's method with SmartPy

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy

How can I call a smart contract method from another smart contract with smartPy?

*Use Case:*

Lest's imagine that we have:

1. Smart contract with a function **increment(a)**
2. Smart contract with a function **changeVarValue() that invokes the first Smart Contract's increment method**.

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you share your code for reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example template here: https://smartpy.io/dev/index.html?template=collatz.py.

The documentation is here: http://smartpy.io/dev/reference.html#_contract_and_address.

Basically:

- define your target contract
- `c = sp.contract(sp.TInt, address_of_the_target_contract, entry_point = "foo").open_some()`
- use `sp.transfer(-42, sp.mutez(0), c)`